# class variable after load image

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

when i change variable after load image, so in gameloop i have old value..
what i am doing wrong?

```
var symb ;
var Symbol=function(imgSrc) {
    this.loaded=false;
    this.img=new Image();
    this.img.onload = function () {
        this.loaded=true;
        console.log("in loaded - " + this.loaded);
    }
    this.img.src=imgSrc;
}
Symbol.prototype = {
  getLoaded: function()
  {
      return this.loaded;
  }
}

symb=new Symbol("images/worm.jpg");
console.log("after loaded - " + symb.getLoaded());
setInterval(testSymbolsLoaded, 3000);

function testSymbolsLoaded() {
    console.log("after 3 second loaded - " + symb.getLoaded());
}
```

this code return

```
after loaded - false
in loaded - true
after 3 second loaded - false
```

why the last value is false, when earlier was change to true??

thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.img.onload = function () {
    this.loaded=true;
    console.log("in loaded - " + this.loaded);
}
```

Within the function, `this` is referring to the context of the image. You'll need to bind the function to the existing `this`:

Fix:

```
this.img.onload = function () {
    this.loaded=true;
    console.log("in loaded - " + this.loaded);
}.bind(this);
```